# I can't use the data in the outer class form the inner class i have created

Tags: java, android, sqlite

As you can see, I want to create an outer class to be an adapter between my activity and my data base to make it more secure nut it just refuse to use the values from the inner class, i have tried to import the values but it doesn't make sense to import them and i'm trying to hide them
can you solve this problem or give me another way to put my code to work

```
public class DataBaseConnection {
    DataBase DataBase;
    public DataBaseConnection(Context context)    {
         DataBase = new DataBase(context);
          public void  dataInsert (String classnumber , String studentsnumber) {
         SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DataBase.classname);
            contentValues.put(DataBase.studentsnumber);
        }
    }

    class DataBase  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String database_name = "DB";
        private static final int database_vesion =1;
        private static final String UID = "id";
        private static final String name = "Name";
        private static final String work_mark = "Works Mark";
        private static final String test_mark = "Tests mark";
        private static final String tableName = "Students";
        private static final String classname = "Class name";
        private static final String studentsnumber = "Students number";
        private Context context;
        private static final String tablename1 = "Class";
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " +tablename1+" " +
                " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                " "+classname+" TEXT VARCHAR(255))," +
                " "+studentsnumber+" INTEGER ;";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +tableName+" " +
                " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                " "+name+" TEXT VARCHAR(255))," +
                " "+work_mark+" INTEGER ," +
                " "+test_mark+" INTEGER ;";
            private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +tableName;
            private static final String DROP_TABLE1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "  +tablename1;

        public DataBase(Context context) {
            super(context, database_name,null, database_vesion);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);

            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE1);

            onCreate(SQLiteDatabase,db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using the same name for classes and instances. Variable names go camelCase always.

Comment: "onCreate(SQLiteDatabase..." just mentioning a class name here is an error.

Comment: Private items of a class are inaccessible for the outer class

Comment: @MichaelButscher but i have mentioned the inner class in the outer, I will change it to public and give you a feedback

Comment: Those variables belong to the class, not the instance, reference the Inner class variables directly, not through the instance .. also I'm not sure how you are making anything "secure" using a inner class - I think you want encapsulation and abstraction.

Comment: can any one please edit the wrong parts of the code for me?

Comment: @MichaelButscher - "Private items of a class are inaccessible for the outer class" untrue - I believe you are confusing static nested class (which is basically a top level class), with inner class

Comment: @MarkKeen Right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems, you have placed a function inside a function, which is not valid syntax - it has nothing to do with class variable visibility. Also to not really sure how this approach is more secure seeing as your database variable is package scoped. To resolve your immediate problems you need something like this :

```
public class DataBaseConnection {

    private final DataBase dataBase;

    public DataBaseConnection(Context context)    {
        dataBase = new DataBase(context);
    }

    public void dataInsert (String classnumber , String studentsnumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DataBase.classname, classnumber);
        contentValues.put(DataBase.studentsnumber, studentsnumber);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert( // insert here  )
    }

.. Rest of class

}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot!! being a noob is so hard, I wish I could finish this app at the end of this day to give it tomorrow to m school teacher who understand nothing in this code,It's hard to be in a place where there;s no one to help you or to teach you something,You are my hero man Thanks alot!!!!.

Comment: oh sorry but i after i added this code and inserted data from my activity the app crashes